# How can I display elements from these two nested ng-repeats in the same table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I am wondering how I can properly display the repeated elements of two arrays in a table. I think my issue may be with the elements coming from nested ng-repeat's. Here is a simplified version of my problem that I created in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpvuIjEKvJ2MLzPfFrfo?p=preview):

```
         <table>
            <tr>
                <div ng-repeat="data in pTab">
                    <div ng-repeat="headers in data.modelHeaders">
                        <th>{{headers}}</th>
                    </div>                                                              
                </div>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div ng-repeat="data in pTab">        
                    <div ng-repeat="modelArrays in data.modelData">
                        <div ng-repeat="specs in modelArrays">
                            <td>{{specs}}</td>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                                  
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I can see the elements here, I'm trying to put them in a table so that I can align the headers above the corresponding specs.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in pTab">
        <div ng-repeat="headers in data.modelHeaders">
            <h3>{{headers}}</h3>
        </div>                                                              
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="data in pTab">      
        <div ng-repeat="modelArrays in data.modelData">
            <div ng-repeat="specs in modelArrays">
                <p>{{specs}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>                                                                  
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LpvuIjEKvJ2MLzPfFrfo?p=preview

I'm doing this so that I can display the headers and specs aligned properly as a table. How can I make display these elements in the same table when I need multiple ng-repeat divs?

Let me know if you need more information or anything else from me.

**EDIT**

There are more elements in pTab and modelData. Here is an updated plunker with a more detailed model of my data:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3k6Ew5YWFQhDw77UpSB8?p=preview

Note: I use a different function to show the proper model and specs. I just use `ng-if="$first"` to simplify the demo.

Comment: Shouldn't `modelArray` be array of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You need little management of ng-repeat over your data and follow the hierarchical traversal of data in pTab:-

```
<table>
            <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="header in pTab.data.modelHeaders">
                        <span>{{header}}</span>
            </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="spec in pTab.data.modelData.modelArray">
                            <span>{{spec}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tl63e4dDC3PykeYeJHM3?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, those elements aren't actually name "data" and "modelArray" and there are many of each. This is why I have the nested repeats. Here is a plunker with a better representation of my data:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3k6Ew5YWFQhDw77UpSB8?p=preview

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note: I use a different function to show the proper model and specs. I just use `ng-if="$first"` to simplify the demo.

Comment: First of all if you are using tables rememeber that tr next element must be a td :-p not a div i will check it. your data in pTab is array or not ?